# How to solve an error "THREE.WebGLRenderer.readRenderTargetPixels: readPixels from renderTarget failed" by using 3D-markup Demo

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I did "git clone" and open the app on Chrome browser

https://github.com/wallabyway/markupExt

It causes an error "three.js?v=v3.3:35 THREE.WebGLRenderer.readRenderTargetPixels: readPixels from renderTarget failed. readPixels error 1282"

How can you solve this?

There is the same issue: https://github.com/wallabyway/markupExt/pulls

I appreciate if someone merge the PRs.

My final goal is to use the 3D-markup extension with Vierwer version 7.87

---

Update:
the above error was resolved when I updated the Viewer version to v.7.* according to a pull request.

Comment: Checking with the repo owner.

Answer (score 1):

Merged (sorry for the delay).  Thanks Eason for pinging me ;-)